# How to Create Web Site ARM Template with Managed Identity?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to create Azure Resource Manager templates for several web sites that read secrets from a key vault.   In reading [How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity), the documentation states that the web site ARM template should contain the following upon creation for authenticating with a key vault:

```
"identity": {
   "type": "SystemAssigned"
}
```

Once the web site is created, the the `identity` section changes to the following:

```
"identity": {
   "type": "SystemAssigned",
   "tenantId": "<TENANTID>",
   "principalId": "<PRINCIPALID>"
}
```

*Does this mean that after running the ARM templates to create the web sites that I have to go back into the ARM template(s) and update the `identity` section for every site so that I can run the ARM templates to update the sites if need be?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you dont have to do that. that is expected. it will not delete that. just rerun it and nothing will change.